# How to write VBA to format sentence starting with // in Word 2016?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a 400+ page coding manual I use, and unfortunately turned off the green for all the comments in the manual. I can't undo it, as I hadn't noticed it until it was too late. Its ruined years of work.

How would I write VBA to parse the document finding sentences starting with // and ending in a Paragraph mark and change the color of them? Or assign a style to them?

Here is a start that I have cobbled together, I admire people who can write code without intellisence, its like trying to find your way blindfolded

```
    Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim text As String

    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
     If Len(oPara.Range.text) > 1 Then
           Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(oPara.Range.Start,oPara.Range.End)

    With rng.Font
            .Font.Color = wdColorBlue
    End With
     End If
    Next
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim text As String

For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
   text = oPara.Range.text
   'Check the left 2 characters for //
   If Left(oPara.Range.text, 2) = "//" Then
     oPara.Range.text = "'" & text
   End If
Next
```

I assume you are using VBA so by placing a ' in front of // it will turn the line green.  You could modify the code to replace // with ' if desired.  The opera.range.text should grab the entire paragraph.